# Centering header (includes logo & navigation)

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm working on the header of a website. I've looked around stackoverflow for instructions on how to center the header (includes logo & navigation bar).

I'm using Dreamweaver CC and when I click the preview button, it shows up on the browser centered, but the right has more white space than the left.

My current CSS:

```
.container { 
    width: 1000px; 
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center; 
}

.header_left { 
    float: left; 
    width: 300px;
}

.navi { 
    float: right; 
    width: 600px;
}

.navi li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

My Current HTML:

```
<body id="home">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header_left">
  <a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_04.jpg" width="208" height="69"/></a>
        </div>
            <div class="header_right">
                <ul class="navi">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_07.jpg" width="88" height="56"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_09.jpg" width="88" height="56"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_11.jpg" width="88" height="56"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_13.jpg" width="88" height="56"></a></li>
                </ul>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
            </div>
   </div>
```

EDIT: [Sample of what it looks like](http://jsfiddle.net/zz2Dy/)

Comment: To me, there seems to be zero whitespace on left and right of the header, which makes sense since it has a width of 100%. This becomes especially clear when you [give it a background](http://jsfiddle.net/WAR4r/8/).

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler Sorry, fixed jsFiddle. The previous one wasn't mine. I was just examining it.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what you want. Do you want to center the elements inside the header element? In your fiddle I don't see any elements inside the header.

Comment: @LeonardoManrique I accidentally put a wrong jsFiddle. I fixed the link. I used sample pictures found on the web. It's best to enlarge the result space. I'm not sure if it's my eyes or something, but the right side of the page has more white space than the left making it look not center. I'm trying to get it centered on the page with equal margins.

Comment: It's centered. I used a ruler.

Comment: As a comment, if you want to center an item would be good to use [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/). I don't put the answer because I used deprecated properties.

Comment: @LeonardoManrique, I don't think flexbox support is ubiquitous enough yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to understand the problem.  The header as a whole is centered. The elements inside have margin issues due to specifying width on the images and then giving the class a different width as well. You can remove the width in the class and it will push each floated element flush to the their specified sides. Then add margin to push them the distance you would like:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    background: #333;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.header_left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
.navi {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 60px;
}
.navi li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/zz2Dy/3/

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! The only thing I don't understand is `body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}`

Comment: No problem!  I was just getting rid of the scroll bar.  You can leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

text-align:center and float don't make good friends :)

test this : setting ul as inline-block element and not floatting: http://jsfiddle.net/zz2Dy/2/

```
.container { 
    width: 1000px; 
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center; 
    background:#333;
}

.header_left { 
    float: left; 

}

.navi { 
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}

.navi li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right header element has the property `text-align: center`, and it doesn't occupy the entire width of the element, so it ends up with more white space on the right. If you add to your fiddle the class:

```
.header_right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

That should remove the white space on the right.

(if I understood your issue properly)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.header_left {
    display: inline-block;
}
.header_right {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navi { 
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
.navi li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zz2Dy/4/)

Basically, I've removed floats and widths and padding, used `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="../images/bestfoodservicesweb_07.jpg" style=" display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;"/>
```